# Two Level filter OR/AND

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a 2 level filter where the first filter is an OR and the second is an AND

This means you can choose just one option of Filter 1 and as many options as you like in Filter 2

This filters work by using classes

The list of elements that are being filtered have specific classes, first a month (filtered with **Filter 1**), then categories (filtered with **Filter 2**)

When using the filter, if a month is selected by Filter 1, the element with that month as a class will be displayed

But as soon as a category is selected, it has to display the elements from that month and with that category

Up to this point, it works

**The idea is that when a second category is selected, it has to display the elements from that specific month and with EITHER one of the categories selected**

---

Example:

Filter 1: **July**

Filter 2: **Societies**, **Campaigns**

Result:

Event (July Societies)   --> Just one of the categories

Event (July Campaigns)   --> Just one of the categories

Event (July Societies $ Campaigns)   --> Both of the categories

[I've created a fiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/kcrmgqae/6/)

```
$('.press').click( function() {
    const checked = $(":checked");
    var filtered = "";

    if (checked.length === 0) {
        return $(".event_item").show();
    }

    $(".event_item").hide();

    checked.each(function() {
        filtered = filtered + "." + this.id;
    });

    $(".event_item" + filtered ).show();
});
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working. when i run your fiddle it seems to run just fine

Comment: But in your example(in Fiddle) it's already working that way! if you choose `july` and then `societies` and `campaigns` as filters, doenst exist one, so will not show anything... but if you choose `sportsclub` as filter, will still show that event.

Comment: In my example it shows the elements that have all of the categories selected. What I want to achieve is show the elements with AT LEAST ONE of the categories, not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your radio and your checkbox works in two different ways so you need to create two variables, one for `[type="radio"]:checked` and one for `[type="checkbox"]:checked` and form the selector to show from it.

For each categories selected, concat it with month selected and then join them with `,`.

Example:

Filter 1: July

Filter 2: Societies, Campaigns

=> Selector created: `.event_item.july.societies, .event_item.july.campaigns`

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLzc8jgk/2/)